# Diferencia entre transferir tu dominio a un sitio externo a tu registrador actual /asignar tu dominio sin moverlo de tu registrador actual

Tags: wordpress, dominio

Actualmente he adquirido un dominio y quiero asignarlo a mi sitio de wordpress. Cuando lo intento, me da dos opciones:

1. Transferir mi dominio a WordPress.
2. Asignarlo sin moverlo de mi registrador actual.

¿Cuáles son las diferencias?

Por intuición hemos elegido ‘Transferir a WordPress’ y nos muestra este mensaje:

> Los dominios recién registrados no se pueden transferir. El dominio mima-tdescanso.com se registró hace 1 días y puede transferirse a partir del 17 de julio de 2019.

¿Quiere esto decir que hasta la fecha indicada no podremos hacer nada?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explico:

**Transferir un dominio** significa cambiar la empresa que administra el registro de su dominio. Por ende, si ha registrado un dominio con una empresa y por algún motivo, por ejemplo por precio o por calidad de atención, desea que éste sea registrado a través de otra empresa, es posible transferirlo.

**Apuntar o asignar un dominio**

Si tienes un dominio que gestionas en otro registrador (no lo tienes registrado en empresa1) y quieres utilizarlo en tu hosting de empresa2, debes apuntarlo al hosting de empresa2. O sea, colocar los dns que te brinda la empresa 2. Empresa1 te va a manejar el dominio y empresa2 el DNS o el portal web.

Si solo quieres apuntar la web y mantener los otros servicios de los que dispongas en empresa1, por ejemplo el correo,  tienes que loguearte en el panel de control del empresa1 donde estas gestionando las dns de su dominio y apuntar el host www a la IP del servidor de empresa2.

**Actualización:**
Apuntar o asignar un dominio, es por ejemplo el dominio lo pagas en godaddy yel hosting en wordpress.com. Debes administrar los DNS en godaddy, por tanto para conectar el dominio con tu hosting de wordpress.com debes entrar a godaddy y colocar la ip que te han dado en wordpress.com para poder enlazar (o apuntar) el dominio a la dicho hosting donde tienes la web. Posiblemente tengas el correo con G-Suite, entonces en godaddy debes apuntar el correo a G-Suite.

Cuando transfieres el dominio a Wordpress.com, entonces, el dominio y hosting se pagan y se administran en wordpress.com y cualquier inconveniente que tengas, ellos te pueden ayudar. Es posible que al transferir el dominio los precios de renovación y registro del dominio sean diferentes.

Espero que puedas entender. De lo contrario comenta y te actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta. Sigo sin entender muy bien lo que significa apuntar o asignar un domino. En cualquier caso, yo ya tengo un dominio comprado (entiendo que el dominio es lo que va en la URL), y lo que quiero es comenzar a construir la web con wordpress sin pagar nada, puesto que ya he pagado por el dominio y por el hosting. ¿Qué es lo que tengo que hacer?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta. @JorgeGarcíaCano